# How to make primeng table paginator smaller?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have primeng ("primeng": "^15.4.1",) table (p-table) with paginator and I am not able to resize the paginator. I would like to make it smaller according to the font in the table.

My .html:

```
<div class="table-container">
  <p-table
      [value]="displayedEvents"
      [paginator]="true"
      [rows]="10"
      [style]="{'font-size': '0.8em'}"
      styleClass="p-datatable-sm"
      >

      <ng-template pTemplate="header">
          <tr>
              <th>Název</th>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Datum</th>
          </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-event>
          <tr>
              <td>{{ event.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ event.id }}</td>
              <td>{{ event.date.toISOString().split('T')[0] }}</td>
          </tr>
      </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</div>
```

For now, it looks like this (obviously too big compared to the other parts of the table):
[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fPAm.png)

Thank you for advices :)